# How to make a Auto Reply Event for DM's

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this Code but I cant get it run with the Command so I can turn it on and off:

```py
auto_dm = "off"

@bot.command()
async def autoreply(ctx, mode: str):
""" On or Off """
    await ctx.message.delete()
    auto_dm = mode


class Events(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        while auto_dm == "on":
            if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
                if message.author.id != bot.user.id:
                    automsg = config.get("automessage")
                    await message.channel.send(automsg)
                    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
                    print(f"{time} | {Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}[Event]{Fore.RESET} | Auto Reply Message send to {message.author}")
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

My Problem is that the Event isn't listening when I set it to "on".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never `on` cause you're not editing the `auto_dm` variable, you need to use the `global` keyword in the `autoreply` command in order to change it

```py
@bot.command()
async def autoreply(ctx, mode: str):
    global auto_dm
    await ctx.message.delete()
    auto_dm = mode
```

Also there are a couple of things wrong with your code

1. The `Events` cog doesn't have an `__init__` method
2. You don't need a while loop in the `on_message` event, there's no purpose for that
3. You should use booleans instead of `on/off`
4. You don't need the `else: pass`, simply don't put it

Here's the cog fixed

```py
class Events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return # Exiting if the author of the message is ourself

        if auto_dm == 'on': # I'd really recommend you using True/False
            if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
                automsg = config.get("automessage")
                await message.channel.send(automsg)
                time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
                print(f"{time} | {Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}[Event]{Fore.RESET} | Auto Reply Message send to {message.author}")
```