# python 3 Discord How do i send a users dm reponse to a specific server channel

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
        msg = message.content
        print(msg)
        channel = (796761485996982302)
        await Bot.channel.send(msg)
        await Bot.process_commands(message)
```

When a user messages the bot it will pop up in the terminal but i have tried to make it so it will send the response to the server channel i choose but it has failed each time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Auto Reply Event for DM's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446531/how-to-make-a-auto-reply-event-for-dms)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a channel and then send the msg

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(m):
    if not m.guild and not m.author.bot:
        await bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).send(m.content)
    await bot.process_commands(m)
```